# Physical meaning of each component of the metric tensor in GR

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, matrix-elements

I am searching, without success, what is the meaning of each component of the metric tensor in the context of General Relativity.

$$
g_{\mu\nu}=\left[\begin{matrix}g_{00}&g_{01}&g_{02}&g_{03}\\g_{10}&g_{11}&g_{12}&g_{13}\\g_{20}&g_{21}&g_{22}&g_{23}\\g_{30}&g_{31}&g_{32}&g_{33}\\\end{matrix}\right]\ 
$$

Comment: Hi, MH info, Welcome to Physics StackExchange! Have you checked the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Examples) entry?

Comment: In GR especially, there is almost no meaning to individual components of the metric tensors because they depend on the choice of coordinate system. The only things you can attribute physical meaning to are scalars constructed out of the metric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity (and for easier drawing) let us
first consider a metric in 2-dimensional space
instead 4-dimensional space-time, i.e.
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{bmatrix} g_{11} & g_{12} \\ g_{21} & g_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$

Now consider a unit-parallelogram in this 2-dimensional space,
with both its coordinate differences $=1$.

[image]

It has side lengths $a$ and $b$, and an angle $\theta$ between the two sides.
Then, according to the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines),
the diagonal $\Delta s$ of this unit-parallelogram is given by
$$(\Delta s)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\theta$$

For a general parallelogram (with arbitrary coordinate
differences $\Delta x_1$ and $\Delta x_2$) its diagonal length $\Delta s$
is given by
$$(\Delta s)^2=a^2(\Delta x_1)^2+b^2(\Delta x_2)^2+2ab\cos\theta\ \Delta x_1\ \Delta x_2$$

That means the metric is
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{bmatrix} g_{11} & g_{12} \\ g_{21} & g_{22} \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} a^2 & ab\cos\theta \\ ab\cos\theta & b^2 \end{bmatrix}$$

which gives you the geometric meanings of all the metric components.

Now you can repeat this reasoning in 3-dimensional space
(using a [parallel-epiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) instead of a parallelogram)
or in 4-dimensional space-time.

The diagonal metric components $g_{ii}$
give the square of the length of the unit-parallel-epiped
in $x_i$ direction.
And the off-diagonal metric components $g_{ij}$ are related
to the angle between the $x_i$ and $x_j$ direction.

- $g_{ij}=0$ : they are orthogonal,
- $g_{ij}>0$ : there is an acute angle ($<90°$) between them,
- $g_{ij}<0$ : there is an obtuse angle ($>90°$)  between them.

Answer (score 5):

This is like finding the meaning of individual coordinates of a classical position vector.

The vertical component has something of a special meaning because gravity is vertical and it matters to just about everything we do. Inside the space station, it isn't so important.

East and North have meaning if you don't want to get lost. But nothing in physics keeps me from basing a map on NorthEast and NorthWest.

Comment: That’s true. But why are we often using only the diagonal elements of the matrix (like g_00, g_11, g_22 and g_33). Why some of the components are equals to 0, and what does it mean?

Comment: Any symmetric matrix say $g_{ik}$ can be diagonalized. The diagonal components $g_{ii}$ are then eigenvalues of the matrix and are invariant.

Comment: @JanG is right. symmetry and antisymmetry are important properties a tensor may have. These properties are related to which components are $0$. See [Tensors as measuring sticks II: symmetry and antisymmetry](https://michaelragone.com/2021/05/21/tensors-as-measuring-sticks-ii-symmetry-and-antisymmetry/) for more.

Comment: The OP is taking a  introduction in GR right now , can we not speak so complicated?

Answer (score 3):

It is perhaps better to exercise with simpler examples before deal with GR to have an intuition on the metric tensor.

Plane coordinates $xy$ with non-orthogonal axis leads to a metric with non-zero diagonal elements. On the other hand, polar coordinates $r \theta$ in the plane, where the basis vectors are perpendicular for every point, has zero diagonal elements.

Back to GR, the Schwarzschild metric $t, r, \theta, \phi$ has the unit vectors mutually orthogonal at every point. Its diagonal elements are also zero.

Comment: Hi.I get what you mean but OP is taking a introduction in GR right now so I dont think this answer is helpful.Well it is correct , but it isnt helpful.

Comment: I am upvoting only because it is correct and anything scientifically correct must be upvoted but I dont think its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

GR uses tensors to describe spacetime.A tensor is a vector in non-Euclidean space of any dimension.Any tensor can be written in the form of a nxn matrix.

[image]

Note that the matrix which describes a non-Euclidean space is a upper or a lower triangular matrix because the angle between dimensions i,j is the same with the angle between dimensions j,i.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial answer is $$g_{ik}(x) = G(e_i,e_k)$$
where $G$ is the abstract bilinear symmetric map form tangent vectors at point $x$ to the the number field, defining the local geometry, and $e_i = \partial_{x^i}$ is the local basis of tangent vectors, defined by translation of a point with all coordinates constant except $x^i$.

The triviality is best seen by the mixed metric tensor, that pairs coordinate differentials a
md tangent vectors
$$g^i_k = G(dx^i,e_i) = \delta_{ik}  = \partial_{x^1}\ dx^k$$
So the diagonal elements are the euclidean lengths squared, the off-diagonal elements are what is called the cos-theorem in euclidean geometry
$$g_{ik} = e_i . e_k = |e_i||e_k| \quad \cos (e_i,e_k)$$
In space time $g_{00}$ measures the proper time squared along a curve, positive for a physical worldline and negative for spatial distances. The off-diagonal space-time elements $g_{0k}$ measure Lorentz boost angle between time and spatial directions in the sense of the cos-theorem with imaginary angles.